# Running a forward proxy server in nodejitsu using node js

Tags: node.js, proxy, nodejitsu

I am new to proxy server. What I want to do is: I want to write some node.js code, and then upload to my nodejitsu account to run as a proxy server. Then I would like to use my nodejitsu proxy server on my computer, by configuring the http proxy as "**abc.jit.su**" (my jitsu URL), and the port as "**80**" in Chrome, Firefox or IE. That's to say, I want my nodejitsu proxy server to have the same function as the proxies listed here: http://www.freeproxylists.net/. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can write a simple proxy using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module, like this:

```
var http = require('http'),
    request = require('request');

// For nodejitsu, this will be port 80 externally
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  req.pipe(request(req.url)).pipe(res)
}).listen(port);
```

However, this will only work with http, not https.

Nodejitsu also produces a [proxy module](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy), you may get some ideas on what to do next by looking at that.